# Multiple files for reading abbreviations?

Tags: abbrev, libraries, load

Is it possible to have multiple files to tell emacs reads abbrevs? In other words I would like that emacs reads abbrevs from files `A` and `B`, but write abbrevs only in `A`.

Is it possible?

```
(setq abbrev-file-name "~/.emacs.d/abbrev_defs")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An abbrev file contains regular Lisp code and is evaluated using `load`. Therefore all you need to do is to add `(load B)` (with B being the full path to file B) to your init file wherever appropriate.